# Clipping out polygon into buffer layer so that buffer layer shows dominant feature from polygon layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, clip, land-use, intersect

What I am trying to do is clip out a land use layer for the city of Boulder, CO within the confines of a 500ft buffer that I have created for a bunch of road segments. Beyond that I'm trying to get each road segment buffer to only show the dominant land use type.

Here's an image to help visualize a bit:

[image]

I have the road segment buffer selected and you can see the land use polygon underneath. Obviously here the yellow land use type is dominant and, as such, I would like for the buffer to clip that out and apply it to the buffer entirely. Other road segments aren't as clear though so I need some way to compute and automate this.

Is this possible?

If not, I'm just trying to show the dominant land use type is per road segment in order to see how a road, and its users, are impacted by said land use as part of a larger study, but I'm at a loss for how to actually do this. This is what I thought would be best, but I'm open to another method entirely if you have an idea.

Comment: FelixIP's answer on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-for-desktop/217747?noredirect=1#comment334280_217747 is what you need.