# Calculating predominant value according to area within polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, shape-area

I am using QGIS 2.18.1 Las Palmas, in Windows 10, and that's the issue I want to clarify:

I've got 2 polygon shapes. 1- One with river basins, and 2- other one with different levels of dessertification risk:

[image: River basins]

[image: dessertificationrisk]

In the attribute tables for each one, I've got names for each river basin in the first map, and in the second one, I've got 5 different levels (differenced by colors in the picture)

So, what I need is not only cut or intersect both of them. What I need is to know which level of dessertification risk is more predominant, within each river basin. In other words, I need a final shape similar as the river basins shape, but with an additional column saying the level of dessertification risk which occupies the biggest % of surface within each basin.

For example: I will zoom into one of the basins, setting the river basins without filling, so you can see the dessertification risk layer behind:

[image]

We see different colors within the polygon. Initially, it seems that the most predominant color is purple, or could be the light green.

What I need is to determine which one covers the biggest % of surface within this polygon, and set it as a new value for the river basins polygons.

I've tried different things but I don't find the solution.

Comment: Most certainly the ArcGIS workflow http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-for-desktop/217747#217747 can be implemented in QGIS

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP ! I've tried to follow the same workflow, but in step 2, I can't find the option "summarize" in QGIS. Where can I find it? Thanks!

Comment: There is no summarise in my solution, although I'd be surprised if such function does not exist in qgis. I don't know qgis, sorry

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I refer to the case below yours, done by @jbchurchill . In your case, that's exactly what I need to do, but maybe because of my lack of ability with PyQgis I don't know how to implement the workflow in QGIS.

Comment: My solution based 100℅ on tools,no scripts

Comment: Thanks anyway, perhaps I misunderstood it, however, as you can see below, it was solved with a script (my abilities will slowly increase!)

Comment: I am least impressed with QGIS if such a massive efforts are required to solve outmost basic GIS task

Comment: @AlexFernándezPoulussen, please see if my new code worked for you.

Comment: ... And, @FelixIP, I'm really happy to tell you that the time analysis is now of 10 seconds more or less! This happened because I didn't use a QGIS core tool for this specific case ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE** I edited the code because the questioner reported some issues with the results.

---

I have created a sample dataset to reproduce the issue and I have made some assumptions:

- the layer of the river basins (colored with light green) stores the name of each river basin in a field called `"BASIN_NAME"`;
- the layer with different levels of desertification risks (colored with a color ramp of reds) stores the value of the risk in a field called `"RISK_LEVEL"`;
- the level of desertification risk is formatted as an integer value (but this can be easily adapted to your specific needs).

[image]

You may use this script:

```py
# Layer of the river basins
##risks=vector
# Layer with different levels of desertification risk
##basins=vector

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

layer1 = processing.getObject(risks)
crs = layer1.crs().toWkt()
layer2 = processing.getObject(basins)

# Create the output layer
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs='+ crs, 'basins_new' , 'memory')
prov = outLayer.dataProvider()
fields = layer2.pendingFields() # Fields from the input layer
fields.append(QgsField('PREDOMIN_RISK', QVariant.Int, '', 10, 0)) # Name for the new field in the output layer
prov.addAttributes(fields) # Add input layer fields to the outLayer
outLayer.updateFields()

# Create a dictionary and a spatial index with the features from the previous intersection
allfeatures = {}
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for feat1 in layer1.getFeatures():
    index.insertFeature(feat1)
    allfeatures[feat1.id()] = feat1["RISK_LEVEL"]

for basin in layer2.getFeatures():
    inAttr = basin.attributes() # Input attributes
    basin_geom = basin.geometry() # Input geometry
    idsList = index.intersects(basin_geom.boundingBox())
    count = 0
    req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(idsList)
    tmp_dict = {} # Temporary dictionary containing all the features inside the current river basin
    for elem in layer1.getFeatures(req):
        temp_geometry = elem.geometry()
        if basin_geom.intersects(temp_geometry):
            itx = basin_geom.intersection(temp_geometry)
            tmp_dict[elem.id()] = itx.area() # Calculate the area
    if len(tmp_dict) > 0:
        max_key = max(tmp_dict, key=tmp_dict.get) # Evaluate the key with the maximum value of area
        inAttr.append(allfeatures[max_key])# Add the desertification risk value from the feature referring to max_key

    outGeom = QgsFeature()
    outGeom.setAttributes(inAttr) # Output attributes
    outGeom.setGeometry(basin_geom) # Output geometry
    prov.addFeatures([outGeom]) # Output feature

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
```

The code will create a new polygon layer (as memory layer), having the same fields of the river basins layer, plus one additional field (called `"PREDOMIN_RISK"`) where the predominant level of desertification risk that intersects the current river basin is stored.

For example, zooming into one of the river basins (higlighted with a blue circle):

[image]

we will have two different values of desertification risk (the label shows the corresponding value from the field `"RISK_LEVEL"`):

[image]

For this river basin, the attribute table from the output layer will show:

[image]

Comment: Dear @HowToInQGIS thanks soo much! the output is exactly what I'm looking for, however, I couldn't make it work. Perhaps because of my lack of ability with scripts. I've even created a copy of my layers so they have the same name (risks and basins) with the same field names ("RISK_LEVEL" and "BASIN_NAME"). Then I opened the Python console, pasted your script, and click run. The message I get is:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/alex/appdata/local/temp/tmpvnvuxk.py", line 9, in <module>
    layer1 = processing.getObject(risks)
NameError: name 'processing' is not defined

Comment: I don't know if I have to include some aditional info in the script, or something... If you could help me, I would be more than grateful!! I feel like I am so close to get it!!

Comment: The script will work if you use the Processing framework. From the main QGIS Window, go to `Processing` and then click on `Toolbox`. From the `Processing toolbox` (just activated on the right side of the main QGIS window), go to `Create new script` menu under the `Tools` group in the `Script` algorithms block of the toolbox. Then, copy & paste my code and it will magically work! You could be also run it from directly from the Python Console, but you need to change the way with which you interact with the input files. Please let me know if you encounter any other problem.

Comment: For additional referece, see also this [link] (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) from the QGIS Documentation. Once you will be able to work with scripts, it will be very easy to adapt the code to your specific needs (e.g. you may modify it using your original field names).

Comment: It worked!!! I had to wait almost 2 hours to finish processing, I thought it was going to crash, but finally, as you said, magic!! Maybe because of the large number of polygons it took so long, but now I can't exprees my gratitude enough. Trust me, I really needed it and spent 4 days thinking and trying to find the way, so THANKS, an please let me know what can I do for you!!

Comment: I only looked for a working solution (not the best one) and I'm glad it worked for you too. As you said, the time consuming was surely due to the large number of features (despite the using of a spatial index). You have just accepted my answer, so you haven't to do anything more, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think that most time was spent for the preliminary intersection of the features because they seem to be complex (i.e. with many vertices). Instead, the next step should be very fast thanks to the spatial index.

Comment: Hi @HowToInQGIS ! I've got some trouble using this script in other situations... For example, I want to do a similar thing between other 2 overlapping polygon layers. I understand I can use the same script changing the field name I need to be included in the output layer, but the result I get is not fully correct (I've checked and I see polygons in which the predominant value is not the one it should be). I think I need to change sth in the script but I've tried several things and still doesn't work, Should I post a new question so you can help?

Comment: Did the code run without errors?

Comment: yes, the code ran with no errors. Let's see if with images I can explain myself better: I've got one polygon layer (A) of River Basins, ony wit values 1 (blue) and 2 (red): http://imgur.com/gR5BNg6 And another polygon layer (B) also of River Basins, but with different delineation (You can see B in transparent, black borders) : http://imgur.com/rk8ioBf Let's assume that A is the Risks and B the same basins layer. The result I get is this: http://imgur.com/pWa823r  As you can see, there are 3 polygons in red that should be in blue. I don't know why¿? You have any idea? Thanks my friend!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but there could be some problem with the output from the intersection operation. Did you verify if the intersection was correctly returned?

Comment: I've tried to run the intersection operation separatedly, and apparently everything is ok: http://imgur.com/9WglP2W The only thing I could see is that it returns the values of the field I'm interested in string, but I know I can convert it to integer. So still don't know where the problem come from :-(

Comment: Hmm, I can't start doing some tests because I can't reproduce your issue. The best would be if you can select the features I see in the image you posted, saving them (for layerA and layerB) and then uploading them somewehere. If the intersection seems ok for you, you may also loading only the output from the intersection, so it will be easier for me doing some test. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Ok, let's try it. I've uploaded 3 layers: A (the equivalent of risks), B (the river basins) and also the intersection of A and B, if it's of any help. I've uploaded to my dropbox in a folder, let's see if with this link you can have access to the folder: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07aj6gt3v7cd98q/AACtg40dJXlkEgMvVavWXHnVa?dl=0 Let me know if it works ok? And thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Or maybe better try to download from this wetransfer link: https://we.tl/QgC4sN5yKS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52362/discussion-between-howtoinqgis-and-alex-fernandez-poulussen).