# Determining which shapefile lies in another using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to find out which region (shapefile 2) each polygon in shapefile 1 is in.  In some cases it may be in more than one region.  In this case I am trying to determine in which ecosystem (Terrestrial Ecosystems of the World) each of the World's protected areas are in.

I have tried most combination of things in ArcMap 10.3 without success (I can get some to work but not others).

Comment: Have you tried Union and Intersect?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-for-desktop/217747#217747

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute a spatial join with the "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY" option