# Hexabin map from multiple polygon layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, hexagonal-grid, hexagon-binning

I work at urban planning and I am trying to create an hexbin map from landscape use of a small city.

I have different polygons (vector layers) like buildings, roads, gardens, services, industry, and so on... that doesn't overlap.

I also have created a HEXAGONAL GRID (polygons), and each hexagon has 10.000 m2 (1 ha).

My idea is to create something like this:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEiZ9eEVIAApcSO.png

A cool and very interesting alternative to point-based maps, in my opinion...

My first (1) option was to go to:
menu -> Vector -> Geometry tools -> polygon centroid and create a centroid point layer, and then "count points in polygons" but I came to the conclusion that much of the information I have, like what is the use that is predominant inside each hexagon, is lost...

So I am now searching for a method that counts area (% of the 10.000 m2) of the different uses... For example for green areas, what is its predominance inside each hexagons?

How can I "pass" that attribute to the hexagonal shape?

Should I clip building-green areas-industry layers, with the grid, and the perform a spatial join (join by location)?

Or is there another way to perform this?

I am using QGIS 2.14 ESSEN.

____________________EDITING____________________________

To specify my question:

I want to know if it is possible to calculate all red-pink-blue-green area inside each hexagon, knowing that every hexagon has 10.000 m2.

My objective is to know for hexagon ID = n:

```
Building area  = x %
Green area  = x %
Industry area  = x %
Roads area  = x %
```

And for all other 450 Hexagons.

Do I have to clip with the grid and then perform spatial join?

[image]

Comment: Intersect and find dominant land use, see arcgis workflow https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: Can you help I little bit more? I am working with QGIS. Just a simple intersect will do it?

Comment: Sort interest in descending order by area. Remove duplicate rows of grid id. This will leave 1 (dominant!) Land use per grid. Transfer it's name to grid through join

Answer (score 1):

By using PyQGIS, next code calculates, as area percentage of hexagonal (or part of it) feature layer, for each feature belongs to polygon_layer; equivalent to layer with buildings, roads, gardens, services, industry, etc.

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

grid = registry.mapLayersByName('hexabin_grid')
polygon_layer = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon_layer_mult')

feats_grid = [ feat for feat in grid[0].getFeatures() ]

feats_pol = [ feat for feat in polygon_layer[0].getFeatures() ]

for i, fg in enumerate(feats_grid):
    for j, fp in enumerate(feats_pol):
        if fg.geometry().intersects(fp.geometry()):
            total = fg.geometry().area()
            intersect = fg.geometry().intersection(fp.geometry()).area()
            print 'i: {}, j: {}, %area: {:.2f} % of i'.format(i, j, (intersect/total)*100)
```

I tried above code out with multipart layer (equivalent yours with  buildings, roads, gardens, services, industry, etc) and hexabin layer (48 features) of next image:

[image]

and after running it, it was printed at Python Console of QGIS, values of i (feature grid) and j (feature of another polygon layer) indexes and area percentage of features layer inside each feature grid.

```
i: 0, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 1, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 2, j: 0, %area: 74.97 % of i
i: 2, j: 1, %area: 25.03 % of i
i: 3, j: 0, %area: 59.38 % of i
i: 3, j: 1, %area: 40.62 % of i
i: 4, j: 0, %area: 94.50 % of i
i: 4, j: 1, %area: 5.50 % of i
i: 5, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 6, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 7, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 8, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 9, j: 0, %area: 86.99 % of i
i: 9, j: 1, %area: 13.01 % of i
i: 10, j: 0, %area: 26.00 % of i
i: 10, j: 1, %area: 74.00 % of i
i: 11, j: 1, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 12, j: 0, %area: 0.47 % of i
i: 12, j: 1, %area: 99.53 % of i
i: 13, j: 0, %area: 60.14 % of i
i: 13, j: 1, %area: 11.00 % of i
i: 13, j: 2, %area: 28.86 % of i
i: 14, j: 0, %area: 98.69 % of i
i: 14, j: 2, %area: 1.31 % of i
i: 15, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 16, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 17, j: 0, %area: 26.64 % of i
i: 17, j: 1, %area: 73.36 % of i
i: 18, j: 1, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 19, j: 1, %area: 89.17 % of i
i: 19, j: 2, %area: 10.83 % of i
i: 20, j: 1, %area: 84.97 % of i
i: 20, j: 2, %area: 15.03 % of i
i: 21, j: 0, %area: 12.32 % of i
i: 21, j: 2, %area: 87.68 % of i
i: 22, j: 0, %area: 52.67 % of i
i: 22, j: 2, %area: 47.33 % of i
i: 23, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 24, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 25, j: 0, %area: 98.95 % of i
i: 25, j: 1, %area: 1.05 % of i
i: 26, j: 0, %area: 50.64 % of i
i: 26, j: 1, %area: 49.36 % of i
i: 27, j: 0, %area: 6.84 % of i
i: 27, j: 1, %area: 35.87 % of i
i: 27, j: 2, %area: 57.29 % of i
i: 28, j: 0, %area: 22.94 % of i
i: 28, j: 1, %area: 0.58 % of i
i: 28, j: 2, %area: 76.48 % of i
i: 29, j: 0, %area: 17.15 % of i
i: 29, j: 1, %area: 0.21 % of i
i: 29, j: 2, %area: 82.65 % of i
i: 30, j: 2, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 31, j: 0, %area: 41.89 % of i
i: 31, j: 2, %area: 58.11 % of i
i: 32, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 33, j: 0, %area: 60.12 % of i
i: 33, j: 1, %area: 39.88 % of i
i: 34, j: 0, %area: 85.66 % of i
i: 34, j: 1, %area: 7.84 % of i
i: 34, j: 2, %area: 6.50 % of i
i: 35, j: 0, %area: 94.47 % of i
i: 35, j: 1, %area: 2.87 % of i
i: 35, j: 2, %area: 2.66 % of i
i: 36, j: 0, %area: 41.35 % of i
i: 36, j: 1, %area: 10.80 % of i
i: 36, j: 2, %area: 47.85 % of i
i: 37, j: 2, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 38, j: 0, %area: 8.93 % of i
i: 38, j: 2, %area: 91.07 % of i
i: 39, j: 0, %area: 46.51 % of i
i: 39, j: 2, %area: 53.49 % of i
i: 40, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 41, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 42, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 43, j: 0, %area: 100.00 % of i
i: 44, j: 0, %area: 53.63 % of i
i: 44, j: 1, %area: 46.37 % of i
i: 45, j: 0, %area: 50.91 % of i
i: 45, j: 1, %area: 1.14 % of i
i: 45, j: 2, %area: 47.95 % of i
i: 46, j: 0, %area: 31.93 % of i
i: 46, j: 2, %area: 68.07 % of i
i: 47, j: 0, %area: 85.94 % of i
i: 47, j: 2, %area: 14.06 % of i
```

where j indexes would be equivalents to buildings, roads, gardens, services, industry, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for help.

I have to say that I am not that confortable with python language...  So I had to tought of a diferent aproach:

1) INTERSECTed my Hexagonal grid with my polygons
2) Then I used DISSOLVE tool by Hexagonal_ID, while summing area with Dissolve with Stats Plugin
3) So I ended up with a table with every intersect area, by HEXAGONAL ID for every polygon layer

I guess it was a more exhausting methodoly but it worked.

Fell free to comment on my method, or suggest other aproachs.