# Getting map of what cells in raster are contained in different zones of polygon using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 with Spatial Analyst.

I have a few different gridded datasets describing attributes of a city. All those datasets overlay the same gridded area so that the cell in row X column Y for any of those datasets corresponds to the same geographic location.

I also have the city delineated in zones (e.g. Census block groups) in a polygon file.

I need to know which cells in the grid(s) correspond to which zones (block groups) for further analysis. An ideal product would be a raster that is aligned with the other gridded data, with the attribute of the raster being the zone ID that the cell is mostly within. So if three cells of my grids are mostly in zone B, the product I'm after would be a raster grid with the value of those three cells = B.

A little more context in case it matters: Each of my raster datasets has different types of data, some are percentages of an attribute and some are classifications. The important thing is a cell in any of the grids refers to the same place. The polygon with zones lists the zones by a numerical ID. The end goal here is the use the desired product described above to analyze the grids of data zone-by-zone in batch based on the 'zone grid' showing me what cells should be grouped and processed together as each zone.

I've tried using zonal statistics but I don't need statistics about the raster values in each zone, I need a map of what cells are contained within each zone.

Comment: Convert raster to polygons and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/217747#217747

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing dominant area in polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following steps:

1. Convert the raster to a point feature, so the center of each cell in
   the grid becomes a point.
2. Join the attributes of the polygon feature to the newer point feature, based on where the center of each point is.
3. Convert the point feature back to a raster file, carrying over the attribute of interest (polygon zone ID, in this case Census block group) of each point as the value for each raster cell.
4. Set Symbology of the new raster file to Unique Fields using the Value Field = the carried over attribute identifying which zone of the polygon each cell is in, and click "Add All Values"

This gives me the product I was looking for:

> a raster that is aligned with the other gridded data, with the attribute of the raster being the zone ID that the cell is mostly within.