# Grouping data by region in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I have a map of the UK which splits the whole country into 1km polygon squares. Each polygon contains data, and I want to try and group the squares into local authority level.

I have tried overlaying a map and using a spatial join, however this has lots of double counting since the squares on the boundary are counted on both sides.

So I was wondering if there was an alternative method for doing this?

Comment: Intersect and then Dissolve by local authority level.

Comment: Compute dominant area of local authority in each cell https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to have each 1km square assigned to exactly one local authority, you could use the polygon centroids in your spatial join. This may not be an ideal method depending on the data you're dealing with and the what you're using the results for, however.

In Arc, that's Toolbox > Data Management Tools > Features > **Feature to Point**. Select your 1 km squares as your imput and run it. The resulting points layer will retain the attributes of the polygons, but can't be double-counted when you run a spatial join.

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned, but I already tried this as a method, however when I run Feature to Point it returns an error.

Comment: Hmm. Could it be a problem with your grid layer? Try creating a 1 km fishnet and use that instead.