# Statistics for point data within each polygon using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector

I think this is a pretty basic GIS operation but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have hundreds of polygons, and within each polygon there is point data (see picture). The point data has a field "Type" that can either be A, B, C, D, or E. I would like to determine what is the most dominant Type value for each polygon.

How do I go about doing this using ArcMap?

[image: Example]

Comment: If you also seek QGIS answers to the same question please feel free to ask a separate question. All questions are free of charge and more focused questions help you to get more votes to unlock site functionality.

Comment: This is almost exact duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/217747#217747  because your points represent a raster that can be nicely converted into polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Using ArcMap:

[image]

1- Polygon shapefile should have the field (id).

2- Spatial join as follows:

[image]

[image]

3- Summary statistics

[image]

And the final result:

[image]

Comment: Incomplete solution, what is dominant point type for polygon ID = 2?

Comment: Yeah, this solution took me most of the way to the answer. From here I exported to a CSV, then used a Python script to determine the dominant type.