# Extracting attributes from one layer into another layer's different features using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I am trying to work out how to do something in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 and just can't find a way. I have a land use map of an area as seen in the first picture. I have this layer in both polygon and raster layers, see layer below. There are 10 classes of land use each has a different colour

[image: land use map]

I then have a subgrid of around 27,000 squares that I created in fishnet tool, this grid of the area is split into 500m2 squares. as seen below-

[image: subgrid of 500m2 squares]

I would like to know and create a layer showing- in each of these small squares what is the % of land cover from the land cover layer in each small square?

I would then like to extract the values from each square to a point in the centre. So for example, in one square how much of each land cover type is there in the square.

I would then like to create a layer that tells me, for each square, what is the dominant land cover in that square, so for example if there is 20% grassland and80% forest in that square, it would assign the gridcode of forest to that layer

So I will hopefully end up with a layer of 27,000 rows, each row will have a value for each of the 10 landclass types and then another layer where I have 27,000 rows with one dominant value/land cover assigned

Comment: Start with adding a field to your grid (grid_area) and calculate geometry (area) to work out percent later, also add a field (UNIQUEID) and calculate field (FID) for later use (best to add it at the start than to miss it later) then intersect your land use polygons with your grid, add a field (class_area) and calculate geometry, now use summary statistics to tabulate the class_area for each case field land_use and UNIQUEID, this will give you a table with the total area for each grid square in each class.. extract each land use with table select, join by UNIQUEID to the summary table to calc %

Comment: For each land use type the field calculation will be grid_area / sum_table.class_area (as decimal, multiply by 100 to get %). Does that make any sense to you? There's a few steps, I suggest giving it a try with the Esri docs open for each tool in turn and read the description carefully and we can help if you get stuck.

Comment: This will help with one of your multiple questions https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/217747#217747