# Performing overlapping zonal statistics in ArcGIS?

Tags: overlapping-features, zonal-statistics

I have buffer lines overlapping and within these lines I want to know the type of land use. However, overlapping is not allowed with Zonal statistics.

How do I do this in ArcGIS because I want all the data and it's a big dataset. Also I don't know coding (Python).

Comment: Convert raster to polygons and intersect. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/217747#217747

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in QGIS.

If the buffer lines are able to be transformed into a polygon geometry type (either manually through digitizing or through algorithm) you could split them into individual files. Then use an intersection to find the areas where they overlap. These areas would be where you would want to run your zonal statistics.

This can also be done in ArcGIS through the same workflow.