# Slow processing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, vector-grid, land-use

I am working with the vector files:

1. Landuse classification shapefile for a certain area with 4 landuse categories - builtup, vegetation, water and open spaces. (area bounds = 95sqkm). I classified a satellite image of Sentinel-2 in Google Earth Engine and converted the raster classified file to vector in ArcMap.
2. Grids against the same area bounds (grid size 50m x 50m)

I want to get the grids that have an overlapping of 50% or more area with the Built-up landuse from the landuse file.

Is there any tool in ArcMap that can do the job efficiently and quickly?

Comment: You say that one of your vector files is a grid.  Does that mean that it is a fishnet of polygons?  If so, have you tried performing a Union between your two vector datasets?  If so, what happened?

Comment: See if this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/217747#217747

Answer (score 0):

Clip a copy of your land class data with the grid feature. Remove or definition query any clipped bua's with a shapearea less than half of the grid shape area (1250 sq.m). Perform a spatial join or select by location to grab any grids that intersect the bua's. Export the selected grids.