# Classifying a shapefile after a union

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, union

I am trying to classify the Electoral Divisions of Ireland into their land use. To do this, I have obtained the Electoral Divisions shapefile (there are over 3000 polygons), and the Corine Land Cover (CLC) 2018.

I have then done a union on the 2 to join them, but now I am wondering is there a way to classify the electoral divisions with the unified CLC?

At present, I seem to only be able to categorise their colour depending on the electoral divisions OR the CLC.

I am using ArcMap for reference

Comment: ArcGIS is capable of displaying on a combination of unique values, but if you want a true "classification" you might need to add a column and compute a classification value on which to symbolize. It's not clear from your question what you have tried or where you are stuck.

Comment: At present, I have only just joined the 2 shapefiles together using the Union Tool. I wasn't sure how to progress afterwards

Comment: So you're asking about classification, but referring to symbolization, which is a different thing. Both are possible, and are related, but they remain separate tasks. What have you tried, and what problem have you encountered?

Comment: Each division has multiple land covers, so compute majority https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop/217747#217747 or minority.