# Remove polygon outlines from unified polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve

I have a shapefile consisting of Ireland District Electoral Areas (DEA), in which there are over 3000 polygons. Secondly, I have a shapefile consisting of the Land Use classifications in Ireland.

A DEA in the first shapefile can contain many classifications from the second shapefile.

So far, I have followed the steps in [Computing dominant area in polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop) which have given me what I need.

However, I am wondering is there anyway I can delete the classification polygon outlines within the DEA as seen in the screenshot below? As I only need to show the DEAs with these classifications

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways this can be accomplished. As is tagged in your question, one way is to [dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) the polygons based on a common attribute.

Set your dissolve field to the same field that is being used to symbolise your data. Note, this process will create a new dataset. You may also lose other fields in the process.

Another method would be to simply delete the smaller polygons. To do this, in an [edit](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/starting-an-edit-session.htm) session, select the smaller internal polygons using [select by attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm), and press the Delete key on your keyboard.