# Assign grid squares to polygons that most contain them

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, grids-graticules, intersect

I have a featureclass that is a grid of the countries of the world (88,110 squares).
[image]

I am trying to assign all the grid cells to the country that each cell MOST contains (from a shapefile of country polygons).

The example cell shown below is on the border of Mexico and the United States.  It mostly contains Mexico and I would like the corresponding "COUNTRY" field to only assign/populate with "Mexico".[image]

I've performed a union of mygrid2 to a shapefile (world_countries_generalized).  A bit confused on the proper inputs on summarize within and creating a query layer.
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to mention the software you are using.

Comment: I am using the most recent personal use version of ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop#217747

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following workflow:

1. Union your grid with your country boundaries
2. [Summarize your data](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm), grouping by cell ID and county name and computing max area
3. [Create a query layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-layer.htm) joining on cell ID and max area and pass over county name

This approach requires all datasets to be in the same file geodatabase.

Comment: I've performed the union but am a bit confused on the proper inputs for the summarize within step (what input for each blank) and your suggestion of the query layer step.  I've included an updated screenshot above.

Comment: @emwtg2, I have added links in my answer to the appropriate tools.