# Quickly remove overlaps from two polygon layers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology

I have two polygon layers (both very large, up to 1 million rows). One is cadastre (lot boundaries) and the other is building footprints. The latter is rather inaccurate (MS / Daylight layers but is the best I have) and the building footprint often crosses the cadastre lines. I want a quick way to split and delete the overlaps (I know I can do it in Edit/Split, but the dataset is too big to do it all in one (even with a top of the line PC/graphics card). Can I do it with Topology or Spatial Join (somehow?)

Comment: The first part of any answer is to make sure you have spatial indexes for your dataset. Otherwise, there is no avoiding comparing every polygon in the cadastre to every polygon in your building layer. With 1 million rows in each, that's 1 trillion comparisons. That's sure to take a long time.

Comment: Thanks, even with my RTX 3090, it was taking forever. Also, for anyone else having the same issue, I checked and fixed the spatial indexes (not indexed, no comment), and used topology to fix the errors (remove overlap) and ensured that the validation was set to map extent (used a fishnet to manage the area).

Comment: I've built topologies on 27m row polygon FCs. It wasn't even outrageously slow, though I was mostly trying to handle 50-60k sliver polygons. Spatial Join isn't of much use in this context, though you can use a Within relationship from the centroids of the inner features to nominate areas to do further analysis. You probably want to be using an RDBMS solution like PostgreSQL to tackle some of the large-volume comparisons.

Comment: Would Snap work in your situation https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm if your overlaps aren't comparitively large?

Comment: Compute dominant part of their intersect https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop#217747 keep it

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I used a combination of techniques (overlaps too large for Snap) so used Spatial Index and Topology to remove all overlaps that fell outside the boundaries of the cadastre, then used Intersect as per Felix suggestion. Some were left over after both operations, so I calculated a field (Skew = length/area) to find slivers and deleted all too skewed.