# Incorporating raster data into a polygon feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro I have a raster layer that displays the land use of an area by color. I also have a polygon feature layer of the tax parcels of the area. I am looking for a way to find the primary (largest area of parcel) land use for each parcel. I have converted the raster into a polygon layer though I am not sure where to proceed or if this is the correct step for this task.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/computing-dominant-area-in-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop#217747